# Intersection of two forms Follows the Mouse

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

This is the situation:

[image]

I want the **center** of the Intersection part follows the mouse.

What code should I use? (maybe to put it in form1 load event?)

Additional information:

```
    Form1.Height = Val(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height) + 30 [*]
    Form1.Width = 21
    Form2.Width = Val(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width)
    Form2.Height = 21
```

[*]

+30 is the width of the taskbar in my windows. I don't know why but `Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height` does not include total height of my screen resolution (768px).

Comment: FYI `Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height` won't include the space used for your taskbar (or any docked windows/toolbars).  Use `Bounds` if you want to include that space.

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus: currently i can move the Form1 up/down using mouse wheel and Form2 left/right using mouse wheel too.

Comment: @Aaron, please try my answer below. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a timer to your form and set its interval to 10

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Me.Location = New Point(0, MousePosition.Y - 10)  'Form1
        Form2.Location = New Point(MousePosition.X - 10, 0) 'Form2
    End Sub
```

Subtract 10 pixels from the actual position to center your cursor on the intersection itself.

Then on your Form1 Load Event

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
         Me.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
         Me.Height = 21
         Form2.Show()
    End Sub
```

And on your Form2 Load Event

```
    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
         Me.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
         Me.Width = 21
    End Sub
```

Comment: Yeahh! You're great Mr.Ruben! this is exactly what i want :D

Comment: Currently i can't vote up your answer yet because my rep is too low. i will bookmark this and vote for your answer when i have enough rep. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a timer:

```
Public Class Form1

   Dim SecondForm As Form = New Form()
   Dim MouseTimer As System.Timers.Timer = New System.Timers.Timer(10)

   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
      Opacity = 0.5
      BackColor = Color.DarkGray
      Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
      Width = 21
      StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
      Location = New Point(0, 0)
      SecondForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
      SecondForm.Opacity = 0.5
      SecondForm.BackColor = Color.DarkGray
      SecondForm.Height = 21
      SecondForm.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
      SecondForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
      SecondForm.Location = New Point(0, 0)
      SecondForm.Show()

      AddHandler MouseTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf MouseTimer_Elapsed
      MouseTimer.AutoReset = True
      MouseTimer.Start()
   End Sub


   Private Sub MouseTimer_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
      If (InvokeRequired) Then
         Invoke(DirectCast(Sub() MouseTimer_Elapsed(sender, e), MethodInvoker))
      Else
         Location = New Point(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X, 0)
         SecondForm.Location = New Point(0, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y)
      End If
   End Sub

End Class
```